# Load null values in a SQL Query WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, null

How do I load the null values alongside all other conditions.

--  (1) None of the artists were 80 or over
--      and none were 50 or younger when they
--      died.

--  (2) None of the artists were aged 54, 56,
--      71 or 76 when they died.

--  (3) Some of the artists are still alive.

--  (4) Artists who are both German and
--      specialise in Photographic art ('Photo')
--      are excluded.

--  (5) None of the artists have the letter 'o'
--      anywhere in their last name.

--  (6) None of the artists have the first name
--      'Hannah', 'Julia' or 'Frasier'.

```
select artist_id, first_name, last_name, died - born AS age, speciality, nationality
from simon_antiques
where Died - born Not in (54, 56, 71, 76)
  AND first_name NOT IN ('Hannah', 'Julia', 'Frasier')
  AND last_name not like '%o%'
  AND (nationality <> 'German' or speciality <> 'Photo')
  AND (died - born between 50 and 80 or died is null)
Order by last_name
```

This loads all the results but not the artists who are still alive. If i bring the condition out of a bracket it will bring back all people who are alive regardless of other conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first clause in your `WHERE` is only going to match rows where `died` is not null. given that, you can reorder the clauses something like:

```
WHERE first_name NOT IN ('Hannah', 'Julia', 'Frasier')
  AND last_name NOT LIKE '%o%'
  AND (nationality <> 'German' 
    OR speciality <> 'Photo')
  AND ((died - born BETWEEN 50 AND 80 
      AND Died - born NOT IN (54, 56, 71, 76)) 
    OR died IS NULL)
```

This should bring back those that are currently alive.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was brackets.